# Converting UTC to CST in php

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, utc

I want to convert a UTC time to CST using PHP. After googling I got a function

```
function date_convert($dt, $tz1, $df1, $tz2, $df2) {
  // create DateTime object
  $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($df1, $dt, new DateTimeZone($tz1));
  // convert timezone
  $d->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($tz2));
  // convert dateformat
  return $d->format($df2);
}

echo date_convert('2018-05-29 11:44:00', 'UTC', 'Y-m-d H:i:s', 'CST', 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The output is

> 2018-05-29 05:44:00

But when I tried converting **2018-05-29 11:44:00** to UTC using [online converter](https://www.onlineconverter.com/utc-to-cst), I got the result as **05/29/2018 6:44 AM**, which is 1 hour more than what the function returns.

Can anyone help me to find the correct output? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would guess that target timezone is currently in summer time mode, which makes it *CDT*, which is an hour offset. PHP considers this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
function date_convert($time, $oldTZ, $newTZ, $format) {
    // create old time
    $d = new \DateTime($time, new \DateTimeZone($oldTZ));
    // convert to new tz
    $d->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone($newTZ));

    // output with new format
    return $d->format($format);
}
echo date_convert('2018-05-29 11:44:00', 'UTC', 'CST', 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Output:

```
2018-05-29 05:44:00
```

CST is UTC-06, php works well

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain it, but it only seems to happen with EST/CST, even with changing it to a D.

```
$n = new DateTime();  // 'date' => '2018-05-29 09:45:01.000000' America/New_York
$n->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC')); // 'date' => '2018-05-29 13:45:01.000000'
$n->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('EDT')); // 'date' => '2018-05-29 08:45:01.000000'
```

But if you use a place instead of a timezone, it works well:

```
$n->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));  // 'date' => '2018-05-29 09:45:37.000000'
$n->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));  // 'date' => '2018-05-29 08:45:37.000000'
```

I'd suggest using a place such as `America/Chicago` instead.

Comment: Indeed, *always* use the full time zone identifier - as shown in your second example.